# How to fix Makefile error?

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I have created a Makefile. Right now, I get these errors:

- **clang: warning: brians_brain.o: 'linker' input unused**
- **clang: warning: cell.o: 'linker' input unused**
- **clang: warning: cell_grid.o: 'linker' input unused**
- **Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_List_Delete", referenced from:
    _main in brians_brain_cellular_automata.o
  "_List_Read", referenced from:
    _main in brians_brain_cellular_automata.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make: *** [brians_brain_cellular_automata] Error 1**

Here is the Makefile:

```
brians_brain_cellular_automata: brians_brain_cellular_automata.o brians_brain.o cell.o cell_grid.o
    gcc -Wall brians_brain_cellular_automata.o brians_brain.o cell.o cell_grid.o

brians_brain_cellular_automata.o: brians_brain_cellular_automata.c brians_brain.o cell.o cell_grid.o
    gcc -Wall -c brians_brain_cellular_automata.c brians_brain.o cell.o cell_grid.o

brians_brain.o: brians_brain.c cell_grid.o cell.o list.o
    gcc -Wall -c brians_brain.c cell_grid.o cell.o list.o

cell_grid.o: cell_grid.c cell.o
    gcc -Wall -c cell_grid.c cell.o

cell.o: cell.c
    gcc -Wall -c cell.c

list.o: list.c cell.o
    gcc -Wall -c list.c cell.o
```

Assume tabs are properly used.

What confuses me the most is this Makefile worked earlier today. I was typing some code in one of the dependencies and it started doing this. I reverted those changes but I still get these errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this really worked before? `-c` means do a compile but do not link. So most of your rules don't make sense as `.o` files are used for linking and should not be passed to a `-c` command line.

Comment: @kaylum I see what you mean. In this case, what's the best way to create all the object files, then link them together properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiling an object file, you only need to pass in source files, not other object files.  The objects files are used when linking in the executable.  That's the source of the warnings.

As for the error, you're not including `list.o` when linking the executable, nor is it listed as a dependency.  So you're getting "undefined reference" errors for functions in that file.

So your makefile should look like this:

```
brians_brain_cellular_automata: brians_brain_cellular_automata.o brians_brain.o cell.o cell_grid.o list.o
    gcc -Wall brians_brain_cellular_automata.o brians_brain.o cell.o cell_grid.o list.o

brians_brain_cellular_automata.o: brians_brain_cellular_automata.c 
    gcc -Wall -c brians_brain_cellular_automata.c

brians_brain.o: brians_brain.c
    gcc -Wall -c brians_brain.c

cell_grid.o: cell_grid.c
    gcc -Wall -c cell_grid.c

cell.o: cell.c
    gcc -Wall -c cell.c

list.o: list.c
    gcc -Wall -c list.c
```

Since each object file is built the same way, you can actually define a rule using wildcards to compile an object file:

```
brians_brain_cellular_automata: brians_brain_cellular_automata.o brians_brain.o cell.o cell_grid.o list.o
    gcc -Wall brians_brain_cellular_automata.o brians_brain.o cell.o cell_grid.o list.o

%.o: %.c
    gcc -Wall -c $<
```

With this rule, each object file referenced in the `brians_brain_cellular_automata` target will be built with this rule.

Comment: You're the best. What confused me earlier was making sure everything linked properly. For example, some source files depend on others.

Comment: Note that Make knows enough to deduce that `cell.o` is created from `cell.c` without needing to be told again. It also has built-in rules that compile a `.c` file into the corresponding `.o` file; you only need to configure the compilation rule appropriately by setting the macros correctly.  That will make it much easier to change the compilation command lines.  Something similar to the first paragraph is needed; the remainder is not.